# Customize Checkout Html Templates

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.4, knockoutjs, html

Im customizing the checkout of Magento and having some issue in html templates. I copy the cart-items.html from the magento-checkout module in my theme but, when i change the template structure the js stop running and no one error in the console.

```
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">
<div class="title" data-role="title">
    <strong role="heading" aria-level="1">
        <translate args="maxCartItemsToDisplay" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
        <translate args="'of'" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"/>
        <span data-bind="text: getCartSummaryItemsCount()"></span>
        <translate args="'Item in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() === 1"/>
        <translate args="'Items in Cart'" if="getCartLineItemsCount() > 1"/>
    </strong>
</div>
```

Im my template i changed for this

```
<div class="block items-in-cart">
<div class="title" data-role="title">
        <span data-bind="text: getCartSummaryItemsCount()"></span> Item (s)
</div>
```

but the

`data-bind="text: getCartSummaryItemsCount()"`
not working. Can someone explain to me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works but your html structure caused the Items Count (wrapped by the span tag and doesn't has the `strong` tag as the parent) hidden by Magento default CSS.

The best way is wrapping the `span` tag by a `strong` tag (same as magento default) or you have to add custom CSS to display your `span` tag.

The `Item (s)` text should be translated, so your code should be:

```
<div class="block items-in-cart">
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="1">
            <span data-bind="text: getCartSummaryItemsCount()"></span>
            <translate args="'Item (s)'"></translate>
        </strong>
    </div>
```

You can remove `role`, `aria-level` attributes from `strong` tag if you want.